# 'sed' replace last patern and delete others pattern

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching, sh

I want to replace only the last string "delay" by "ens_delay" in my file and delete the others one  before the last one:

Input file:

```
alpha_notify_teta=''
alpha_notify_check='YES'
text='CRDS'
delay=''
delay=''
delay=''
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
alpha_orange='YES'
alpha_orange_interval='300'
alpha_notification_level='ALL'
expression='YES'
delay='9'
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
```

Output file: (expected value)

```
alpha_notify_teta=''
alpha_notify_check='YES'
text='CRDS'

textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
alpha_orange='YES'
alpha_orange_interval='300'
alpha_notification_level='ALL'
expression='YES'
ens_delay='9'
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
```

Here my first command but it doesn't work because it will work only if I have delay as last line.

```
sed -e '$,/delay/ s/delay/ens_delay/'
```

My second command will delete all lines contain "delay", even "ens_delay" will be deleted.

```
sed -i '/delay/d'
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no good way in sed to know if you have reached the last occurrence of some pattern across multiple lines.

Comment: It only changes the last line because you're telling it to: `$` is the address of the last line, and you're using that as the first line of an address range.

Comment: Do you intend for the non-last delay= lines to collapse to a single empty line? Would collapsing to entirely missing be sufficient? Would merely being blank be sufficient?

Comment: Can you sort the file? What if the same key occurs with different values? Is the file small enough that some slow logic would be fine? Does it need to be sed?

Comment: Also, there are details missing here. `vtsisc_delay` occurs in neither. `ens_delay` only occurs in your expected output. Where is the code in context?

Comment: @PaulHodges I already made some corrections

Comment: Please show us a [*simplest* ~complete~ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code and its output, and clarify your requirements. You want 1) all but the LAST line in the file that contain the string `delay` deleted, with no additional special conditions? and 2) you want that line to prepend `ens_` to `delay`, yes? And are the lines order specific, or could you sort the file? More importantly, how big is the file? Is this the only string for which you want duplicates eliminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^delay=/,$!b;/^delay=/!H;//{x;s/^[^\n]*\n\?//;/./p;x;h};$!d;x;s/^/ens_/' file
```

Lines before the first line beginning `delay=` should be printed as normal. Otherwise, a line beginning `delay=` is stored in the hold space and subsequent lines that do not begin `delay=` are appended to it. Should the hold space already contain such lines, the first line is deleted and the remaining lines printed before the hold space is replaced by the current line. At the end of the file, the first line of the hold space is amended to prepend the string `ens_` and then the whole of the hold space is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this kind of thing with sed. There is no way in sed to "look forward" and tell if there are more matches to the pattern. You can kind of look back, but that won't be sufficient to solve this problem.

This perl script will solve it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($seek, $replacement, $last, @new) = (shift, shift, 0);
open(my $fh, shift) or die $!;
my @l = <$fh>;
close($fh) or die $!;
foreach (reverse @l){
    if(/$seek/){
        if ($last++ == 0){
            s/$seek/$replacement/;
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
    unshift(@new, $_);
}
print join "", @new;
```

Call like:

```
./script delay= ens_delay= inputfile
```

I chose to entirely eliminate lines which you intended to delete rather than collapse them in to a single blank line. If that is really required then it's a bit more complicated: the first such line in any consecutive set (or rather the last such) must be pushed on to the output list and you have to track whether this has just been done so you know whether to push the next time, too.

You could also solve this problem with awk, python, or any number of other languages. Just not sed.

Answer (score 0):

Have this monster:

```
sed -e "1,$(expr $(sed -n '/^delay=/=' your_file.txt | tail -1) - 1)"'s/^delay=.*$//' \
    -e 's/^delay=/ens_delay=/' your_file.txt
```

Here:

- `sed -n '/^delay=/=' your_file.txt | tail -1` return the last line **number** of the encountered pattern (let's name it `X`)
- `expr` is used to get the `X-1` line
- `"1,X-1"'[command]'` means "perform this command betwen the first and the X-1 line included (I used double quotes to let the expansion getting done)
- `'s/^delay=.*$//'` the said `[command]`
- `-e 's/^delay=/ens_delay=/'` the next expression to perform (will occur only on the last line)

Output:

```
alpha_notify_teta=''
alpha_notify_check='YES'
text='CRDS'



textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
alpha_hsm_backup_notification='YES'
alpha_orange='YES'
alpha_orange_interval='300'
alpha_notification_level='ALL'
expression='YES'
ens_delay='9'
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
alpha_hsm_backup_notification='YES'
```

If you want to delete the lines instead of leaving them blank:

```
sed -e "1,$(expr $(sed -n '/^delay=/=' your_file.txt | tail -1) - 1)"'{/^delay=.*$/d}' \
    -e 's/^delay=/ens_delay=/' your_file.txt
```

Comment: can you tell me what test.txt do here before | tail ? because I have error `sed: can't read test.txt: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'  `  thank you

Comment: I replaced only  `your_file.txt ` by my iinput file, so what Im suppose to do with `test.txt`

Comment: it delete only the duplicate and keep the last word without replacing it. thank you

Comment: @Hamadagm, it does replace the last word, I have `ens_delay='9'` in my output.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned elsewhere, sed can't know which occurrence of a substring is the last one. But awk can keep track of things in arrays. For example, the following will delete all duplicate assignments, as well ask making your substitution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1=="delay"{$1="ens_delay"} !($1 in a){o[++i]=$1} {a[$1]=$0} END{for(x=0;x<i;x++) printf "%s\n",a[o[x]]}' inputfile
```

Or, broken out for easier reading/comments:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="="       # set the field separator, to help isolate the left hand side
}

$1=="delay" {
  $1="ens_delay"   # your field substitution
}

!($1 in a) {
  o[++i]=$1        # if we haven't seen this variable, record its position
}

{
  a[$1]=$0         # record the value of the last-seen occurrence of this variable
}

END {
  for (x=0;x<i;x++)          # step through the array,
    printf "%s\n",a[o[x]]    # printing the last-seen values, in the order
}                            # their variable was first seen in the input file.
```

You might not care about the order of the variables. If so, the following might be simpler:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1=="delay"{$1="ens_delay"} {o[$1]=$0} END{for(i in o) printf "%s\n", o[i]}' inputfile
```

This simply stores the last-seen line in an array whose key is the variable name, then prints out the content of the array in an unknown order.

Comment: it works but the lines's order of my file is changed and how can I save the modification after this command line. thank you

Comment: I tired your last command to keep the order of my lines but I lost the order. thank you

Comment: @Hamadagm, yes, that's what I said in the answer. If you don't care about the order, use the last version, which does not preserve output order. If you DO care about output order, use the first version, which maintains a separate array (`o[]`) to preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your specifications properly, this should do what you need. Given infile `x`,

```
$: last=$( grep -n delay x|tail -1|sed 's/:.*//' )
```

This `grep`'s the file for all lines with `delay` and returns them with the line number prepended with a colon. The `tail -1` grabs the last of those lines, ignoring all the others. `sed 's/:.*//'` strips the colon and the actual line content, leaving only the number (here it was `14`.)

That all evaluates out to assign 14 as `$last`.

```
$: sed '/delay/ { '$last'!d; '$last' s/delay/ens_delay/; }' x
alpha_notify_teta=''
alpha_notify_check='YES'
text='CRDS'
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
alpha_orange='YES'
alpha_orange_interval='300'
alpha_notification_level='ALL'
expression='YES'
ens_delay='9'
textfileooooop=''
alpha_enable='YES'
alpha_hostnames=''
```

Apologies for the ugly catenation. What this does is writes the script using the value of `$last` so that the result looks like this to `sed`:

```
$: sed '/delay/ { 14!d; 14 s/delay/ens_delay/; }' x
```

`sed` reads leading numbers as line selectors, so what this script of commands do -

First, `sed` automatically prints lines unless told not to, so by default it would just print every line. The script modifies that.

`/delay/ {`...`}` is a pattern-based record selector. It will apply the commands between the `{}` to all lines that match `/delay/`, which is why it doesn't need another `grep` - it handles that itself. Inside the curlies, the script does two things.

First, `14!d` says (only if this line has `delay`, which it will) that if the line number is 14, do *not* (the `!`) `d`elete the record. Since all the other lines with `delay` won't be line 14 (or whatever value of the last one the earlier command created), those will get `d`eleted, which automatically restarts the cycle and reads the next record.

Second, if the line number *is* 14, then it won't `d`elete, and so will progress to the `s/delay/ens_delay/` which updates your value.

For all lines that don't match `/delay/`, `sed` just prints them as-is.

Comment: your command works properly, but I want to keep my changes in the file after running this command: 
`last=$( grep -n delay x|tail -1|sed 's/:.*//' ) | sed '/delay/ { '$last'!d; '$last' s/delay/ens_delay/; }' x` 
Than you

Comment: and I can see that only the sed  works 
`sed '/delay/ { '$last'!d; '$last' s/delay/ens_delay/; }' x` can you explain if I need to use grep too ?

Comment: It works now but like that and don't need the grep `sed -i '/delay/ { '$last'!d; '$last' s/delay/ens_delay/; }' x` . can you explain why dont need grep thank you

Comment: if you ran the `last=$( grep -n delay x|tail -1|sed 's/:.*//' )` line once, then `last` should still be set in your environment. Try this: `echo $last` - should have the line number. then try this - `unset last` - and run it again. Likely to fail. Will add some explanation to the solution. 

When you're ready to make the changes permanent, either redirect the output to a new file, or add the `-i` argument to `sed`.