# Sed - Curly braces needed for a delete expression, not for a substitute one

Tags: regex, bash, sed, curly-braces

In an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289107) I answered these two sed [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289918/4375327):

- First:

  ```
  sed -e "1,$(expr $(sed -n '/^delay=/=' your_file.txt | tail -1) - 1)"'s/^delay=.*$//' \
      -e 's/^delay=/ens_delay=/' your_file.txt
  ```
- Second:

  ```
  sed -e "1,$(expr $(sed -n '/^delay=/=' your_file.txt | tail -1) - 1)"'{/^delay=.*$/d}' \
      -e 's/^delay=/ens_delay=/' your_file.txt
  ```

In the second line, I figured out I needed curly braces around **`/^delay=.*$/d`** to make it work. But it wasn't necessary for **`s/^delay=.*$//`** in the first line (though it works with).

Why this difference?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206908/279389

Comment: The nested `sed` calls to get a line number is a clear indication that you are doing it wrong. Whatever you are hoping to accomplish is probably trivial to rewrite in Awk, and will be much more efficient to boot.

Comment: @triplee I call it a "monster" in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289918/4375327). You should see the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289107). I was trying to answer with a "sed only" line. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304926/4375327) was far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: The answer is a trimmed copy of [Why are these curly braces necessary in sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206908/279389)

Per the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) standard's [page on `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> The script shall consist of editing commands of the following form:
>
> ```
> [address[,address]]function
> ```
>
> where *`function`* represents a single-character command verb from the list in 
>   [Editing Commands in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), followed by any applicable arguments.

So the first non-blank character after the address is taken as a command verb.

The braces are referenced further down:

> ```
> [2addr] {editing command
> editing command
> ...
> }
> ```
>
>   Execute a list of `sed` editing commands only when the pattern space is selected.  …

<sup>[*2addr*] is an indicator that the maximum number of permissible addresses is two.</sup>

To clarify a point made above, the **Addresses** section of [`sed(1)`](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/1/sed.htm) says:

> `Sed` commands can be given with no addresses,
>   in which case the command will be executed for all input lines;
>   with one address, in which case the command will be executed only
>   for input lines which match that address;
>   or with two addresses, in which case the command will be executed
>   for all input lines which match the inclusive range of lines
>   starting from the first address and continuing to the second address. 
>   Three things to note about address ranges:
>   the syntax is *addr1*,*addr2* (i.e., the addresses are separated by a comma);
>           … *(and other stuff not relevant to this discussion)* …

The [gnu info page (`info sed`)](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/sed-3.02/html_node/sed_7.html) has a similar description of `{` and `}`,
under "3.4 Often-Used Commands":

> ```
> { COMMANDS }
> ```
>
>   A group of commands may be enclosed
>     between
>   `{`
>   and
>   `}`
>   characters.
>     This is particularly useful when you want a group of commands to be triggered
>     by a single address (or address-range) match.

Otherwise said, braces are used to apply multiple commands at the same address or to nest addresses.
The standard isn't very explicit here<sup>1</sup> but the left brace `{` *is actually* a command that starts a group of other sed commands (the group ends with a right brace `}`).

1:
though if you read the entire page it is mentioned that:
*Command verbs other than **{**, **a**, **b**, **c**, **i**, **r**, **t**, **w**, **:**, and **#** can be followed by...*

Comment: So the TL;LR is that's how you say "when this address matches and this address also matches", where in this particular case the first address is a range of line numbers, and the second address is a regex. Every address needs an action, but when the action is a block in braces, you can specify additiona\ address/action pairs, inside them, or even go recursive with another pair of braces.